# My heroku postgres psycopg2 (python) query gets slower and slower each time executed. Any insight?

Tags: postgresql, python-3.x, heroku

I have a python app ran on heroku that utilizes a standard postgresql heroku db ($50 version). There are 4 tables within the db. My app queries for one primary key within the main table based off input from the users of my app.

The querying worked great at first however now I'm finding it becoming too slow after about 40-50 minutes without restart my dyno. The queries will take 2,000ms after a while and take several seconds to load in front of the users. I'm newer to programming and this is my second app. I'm wondering what would make queries slower with time instead of constant. They are so fast at first. What are best practices for psycopg2 within an app to ensure the db doesn't get hung up? Here is an example of one of the queries (all others have similar syntax throughout the script):

```js
if eventText=="Mc3 my champs":
            user=event.source.user_id
            profile= line_bot_api.get_profile(user)
            name=str((profile.display_name))

            cur=None
            try:
                cur = conn.cursor(cursor_factory=psycopg2.extras.DictCursor)

                # get the user's information if it exists
                cur.execute("""SELECT lineid, summoner_name, champ_data FROM prestige_data WHERE lineid = %(lineid)s LIMIT 1""", {"lineid": user})
                rows = cur.fetchall()
                for row in rows:
                    champs = row[2]
                    prestige=(calculate_prestige(champs))
                    champs = json.loads(champs)
                    champsdict=dict.items(champs)
                    champs_sorted=sorted(champsdict, key=lambda student: student[1], reverse=True)
                    l=('\n'.join(map(str,champs_sorted)))
                    hello=str(l).replace('(', '').replace(')', '')
                    yay=str(hello).replace("'", "").replace("'", "")
                    msg=(yay+'\n'+"---------------------------"+'\n'+name+'\n'+"Prestige:"+(str(prestige)))
                    line_bot_api.reply_message(
                        event.reply_token,
                        TextSendMessage(text=msg))

                    break                                             # we should only have one result, but we'll stop just in case
                # The user does not exist in the database already
                else:
                    msg = "Oops! You need to add some champs first. Try 'Mc3 inputchamp'."
                    line_bot_api.reply_message(
                        event.reply_token,
                        TextSendMessage(text=msg))               


            except BaseException:
                if cur is not None:
                    conn.rollback()
            finally:
                if cur is not None:
                    cur.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

While I know I did not frame that question well (only been programming for a month), I have found one issue potentially causing this that warrants documentation on here.

I had a suspicion the concurrency issue was caused when incorrect data was not found in the queries. In this situation, my conn would not rollback, commit, nor close in the above example.

Per psycopg2s documentation, even select queries need to be committed or rolled back or the transaction will stand. This in turn will keep your heroku dyno worker focused on the transaction for 30 seconds causing h12. So make sure you commit or rollback each query, regardless of the outcome, with in an application to ensure you do not get an idle transaction.

My queries are spiffy now but the issue persists. I'm not sure what slowly but surely idles my waitress workers. I think some ancillary process is somehow started in one of the class modules I've created which goes indefinitely taking hold of each worker until they are all focused on the transaction which leads to h12.

Would love someones input if they've had a similar experience. I don't want to have a cron job reboot the app every 10 minutes to make this self functioning.

Comment: What do you mean by _spiffy_? Do you commit in the `finally` block?

Comment: The queries ran well. Checked pg:extras and cache hit rate was .98+ for everything, no idle transactions, no outliers, no unused indexes, etc. I have the app running very smooth right now. I changed to gunicorn from waitress/serve. I've heard great things about waitress but I think there was some kind of problem running it with my flask version. Running 3 workers on gunicorn that auto refresh every 300 hits. Also removed the indexed query to a json file loaded when the app is deployed.